# How to efficiently create many documents with Mongoid when one or more violates uniqueness constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-6

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  index({ name: 1 }, { unique: true, name: "name_index" })
```

To create multiple:

```
people = [{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Joe'}]
User.create people
```

This raises

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure:
   E11000 duplicate key error
```

I can see doing

```
people.each do |p| 
  User.create p
  rescue Mongo::Error::OperationFailure
end
```

But this seems very inefficient.

Rails 6
Mongoid 7.2

EDIT: It seems that question was not clear. All valid documents should be created, and the invalid ones should fail silently.

Comment: You can only create one document like that, so the answer to the question in the title is "you can't create them at all".

Comment: @D.SM - Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

To efficiently perform bulk operations, use the driver's bulk API.

https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-bulk-operations/